# In Grafana - how do I display two loki log streams joined by a key field

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki

New to the "loki stack" and promql. pseudocode of what I need might look like this:

for each {app="cronjob1"} ordered by date:

display selected fields

for each {app="eventrouter"} where pod-name = cronjob1.pod-name:

```
display eventrouter log data
```

Any help, or even links to resources is greatly appreciated